# Lapack set internal FORTRAN parameter in C

Tags: c, fortran, lapack, blas

IF you look at [this link](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/dcc/dbdsqr_8f.html), you'll see that MAXITR is an internal parameter of the dbsqr FORTRAN LAPACK routine.

I have found [this link](http://www.xgear.eu/callfortranfromc.html), to call FORTRAN functions in C, but how do I set MAXITR? It doesn't seem to be a parameter. Is there *any* way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MAXITR` is a named constant (aka `parameter`, in C "parameter" means what in Fortran is called "argument") in the subroutine. You have to go to the source code and change it there, if you need that.

```
INTEGER maxitr
parameter( maxitr = 6 )
```

(lines 255--256)

Change the number 6 to whatever you need.

Comment: Is there a way to do it from C? (either at runtime or not)

Answer (score 0):

A Fortran `parameter` is not an argument that can be passed to the function, nor a value that can be modified at runtime. Rather it is a [named constant](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-35421C2D-F664-423E-A503-FFB001592D8E.htm) that is determined at compile time.

So, the only way to modify that value is to change it in the Fortran source code, and compile your own LAPACK.